# Is there a way to override Wordpress' style.css file so that I can use custom CSS on a theme template?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add custom CSS to a theme template that renders an interactive to do list (I am also using some Javascript to make it work). The file name is "dashboard.php," and within it I have tried linking a custom CSS file, but I can't seem to override styles.css (what I believe to be Wordpress' default).

This is the code I am using within dashboard.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * Template Name: Dashboard
 * Template Post Type: page
 */

 get_header();

?>

<header>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/to-do-styles.css">

</header>

    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
  
        <h2>My To Do List</h2>
          
          <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
          <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    
    </div>
  
        <ul id="myUL">
            <li>Hit the gym</li>
            <li class="checked">Pay bills</li>
            <li>Meet George</li>
            <li>Buy eggs</li>
            <li>Read a book</li>
            <li>Organize office</li>
        </ul>

<?php

get_footer ();

?>
```

If I include `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/to-do-styles.css">` in the HTML header, shouldn't that override the default styles.css?

Side note, when I copy the content from `to-do-styles.css` and place it into the template file (dashboard.php), it works fine; however, to keep the template file concise, I would like to have a separate file.

In short, must I override the default `style.css` file, or is there a way to link it to the template?

The following is my code within my functions.php, within my theme folder.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'to_do_list_style');

function to_do_list_style() {

    wp_enqueue_style('/to-do-styles.css', get_stylesheet_uri());

}
```

Comment: The code you are showing isn't the way to go here. You want to show us the code from your theme or child theme that is in the functions.php where it is using the `wp_enqueue_style`

Comment: I have updated my initial post to show my function.php file.

Comment: I believe I have the code in functions.php set up right. How do I link that code to the actual page within the website that I am trying to style?

Comment: Definitely not the correct usage of `wp_enqueue_style` you should review the docs, and also read about requiring dependencies

Answer (score 0):

please use `<head>` instead of `<header>` to include scripts.